# how to create a python script using facepy or facebook-sdk to check facebook notifications of my profile?

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I want to run the script in loop which will check for new notifications in my fb profile.

I used facepy , but using - print graph.get('me/notifications')

requires extended permissions , i.e manage_notifications which I'm unable to get.

```
import facepy
from facepy import GraphAPI

ouath_access_token = ""

graph = GraphAPI(ouath_access_token)

print graph.get('me/notifications')
```

output -

```
{u'name': u'Saumyakanta Sahoo', u'id': u'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\facenotif\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print graph.get('me/notifications')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\facepy\graph_api.py", line 72, in get
    retry=retry
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\facepy\graph_api.py", line 335, in _query
    return self._query(method, path, data, page, retry - 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\facepy\graph_api.py", line 335, in _query
    return self._query(method, path, data, page, retry - 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\facepy\graph_api.py", line 335, in _query
    return self._query(method, path, data, page, retry - 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\facepy\graph_api.py", line 332, in _query
    return load(method, url, data)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\facepy\graph_api.py", line 288, in load
    result = self._parse(response.content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facepy-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\facepy\graph_api.py", line 403, in _parse
    raise exception(**self._get_error_params(data))
OAuthError: [200] (#200) Requires extended permission: manage_notifications
```

Comment: show us what you've got so far and we'll see if we can assist

Comment: edited the description.

Comment: Are you authenticating successfully ?

Comment: yes I can get my name by using - print graph.get('me')

Comment: When You get your access token.There is optional permissions which is not enabled by default. You have to enabled them as well.then your script will run fine.

Comment: I'm unable to find , where is that option ?

Comment: API access to a user’s notifications will be removed for all apps on October 6, 2015, so you might as well stop bothering with this at all now … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Comment: If your app is v2.3 then you can get the notifications by requesting manage_notifications - but as CBroe says above this will be deprecated on October 6, 2015.